# How does Sparks RDD.randomSplit actually split the RDD

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

So assume ive got an rdd with 3000 rows. The 2000 first rows are of class 1 and the 1000 last rows are of class2.
The RDD is partitioned across 100 partitions.

When calling `RDD.randomSplit(0.8,0.2)`

Does the function also shuffle the rdd? Our does the splitting simply sample 20% continuously of the rdd? Or does it select 20% of the partitions randomly?

Ideally does the resulting split have the same class distribution as the original RDD. (i.e. 2:1)

Thanks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For each range defined by `weights` array there is a separate `mapPartitionsWithIndex` transformation which preserves partitioning.

Each partition is sampled using a set of `BernoulliCellSamplers`. For each split it iterates over the elements of a given partition and selects item if value of the next random `Double` is in a given range defined by normalized weights. All samplers for a given partition use the same RNG seed. It means it:

- doesn't shuffle a RDD
- doesn't take continuous blocks other than by chance
- takes a random sample from each partition
- takes non-overlapping samples
- require n-splits passes over data