# Spark - Divide a dataframe into n number of records

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a dataframe with 2 or more columns and 1000 records. I want to split the data into 100 records chunks randomly without any conditions.

So expected output in records count should be something like this,

`[(1,2....100),(101,102,103...200),.....,(900,901...1000)]`

**Here's the solution that worked for my use case after trying different approaches:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61276734/12322995

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark Data Frame Random Splitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40293970/spark-data-frame-random-splitting)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting a possible answer but unfortunately it doesn't answer my question. I have updated my question with a solution and also why the `randomSplit` doesn't work in this scenario

Comment: No problems. I would recommend you to move the solution part to a new answer instead of having it in the question (self-answered questions are fine), following this sites Q&A model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I want the data to be evenly distributed and to be able to use the chunks separately or in iterative manner using `randomSplit` doesn't work as it may leave empty dataframes or unequal distribution.

So using `grouped` can be one of the most feasible solutions here if you don't mind calling `collect` on your dataframe.

`Eg: val newdf = df.collect.grouped(10)`

That gives an `Iterator[List[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]] = non-empty iterator`. Can also convert it into list by adding `.toList` at the end

Another possible solution if we don't want Array chunks of data from the dataframe but still want to partition the data with equal counts of records we can try to use `countApprox` by adjusting `timeout` and `confidence` as required. Then divide that with number of records we need in a partition, which can be later used as `number of partitions` when using `repartition` or `Coalesce`.

`countApprox` instead of `count` because it is less expensive operation and you can feel the difference when the data size is huge

```
val approxCount = df.rdd.countApprox(timeout = 1000L,confidence = 0.95).getFinalValue().high

val numOfPartitions = Math.max(Math.round(approxCount / 100), 1).toInt

df.repartition(numOfPartitions)
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Shaido said `randomsplit` is ther for splitting dataframe is popular approach..

Thought differently about [`repartitionByRange`](https://people.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-nightly/spark-master-docs/latest/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html) with => spark 2.3

> [repartitionByRange](https://people.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-nightly/spark-master-docs/latest/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html) public Dataset repartitionByRange(int
>   numPartitions,
>                                        scala.collection.Seq partitionExprs) Returns a new Dataset partitioned by the given
>   partitioning expressions into numPartitions. The resulting Dataset is
>   range partitioned. At least one partition-by expression must be
>   specified. When no explicit sort order is specified, "ascending nulls
>   first" is assumed. Parameters: numPartitions - (undocumented)
>   partitionExprs - (undocumented) Returns: (undocumented) Since:
>   2.3.0

```
package examples

import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, SparkSession}

object RepartitionByRange extends App {


  val logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("org")
  logger.setLevel(Level.WARN)

  val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName(getClass.getName).master("local").getOrCreate()
  val sc = spark.sparkContext

  import spark.implicits._

  val t1 = sc.parallelize(0 until 1000).toDF("id")


  val repartitionedOrders: Dataset[String] = t1.repartitionByRange(10, $"id")
    .mapPartitions(rows => {
      val idsInPartition = rows.map(row => row.getAs[Int]("id")).toSeq.sorted.mkString(",")
      Iterator(idsInPartition)
    })

  repartitionedOrders.show(false)
  println("number of chunks or partitions :" + repartitionedOrders.rdd.getNumPartitions)

}
```

Result :

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99                                                                                                              |
|100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,155,156,157,158,159,160,161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,171,172,173,174,175,176,177,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186,187,188,189,190,191,192,193,194,195,196,197,198,199|
|200,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218,219,220,221,222,223,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,235,236,237,238,239,240,241,242,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,251,252,253,254,255,256,257,258,259,260,261,262,263,264,265,266,267,268,269,270,271,272,273,274,275,276,277,278,279,280,281,282,283,284,285,286,287,288,289,290,291,292,293,294,295,296,297,298,299|
|300,301,302,303,304,305,306,307,308,309,310,311,312,313,314,315,316,317,318,319,320,321,322,323,324,325,326,327,328,329,330,331,332,333,334,335,336,337,338,339,340,341,342,343,344,345,346,347,348,349,350,351,352,353,354,355,356,357,358,359,360,361,362,363,364,365,366,367,368,369,370,371,372,373,374,375,376,377,378,379,380,381,382,383,384,385,386,387,388,389,390,391,392,393,394,395,396,397,398,399|
|400,401,402,403,404,405,406,407,408,409,410,411,412,413,414,415,416,417,418,419,420,421,422,423,424,425,426,427,428,429,430,431,432,433,434,435,436,437,438,439,440,441,442,443,444,445,446,447,448,449,450,451,452,453,454,455,456,457,458,459,460,461,462,463,464,465,466,467,468,469,470,471,472,473,474,475,476,477,478,479,480,481,482,483,484,485,486,487,488,489,490,491,492,493,494,495,496,497,498,499|
|500,501,502,503,504,505,506,507,508,509,510,511,512,513,514,515,516,517,518,519,520,521,522,523,524,525,526,527,528,529,530,531,532,533,534,535,536,537,538,539,540,541,542,543,544,545,546,547,548,549,550,551,552,553,554,555,556,557,558,559,560,561,562,563,564,565,566,567,568,569,570,571,572,573,574,575,576,577,578,579,580,581,582,583,584,585,586,587,588,589,590,591,592,593,594,595,596,597,598,599|
|600,601,602,603,604,605,606,607,608,609,610,611,612,613,614,615,616,617,618,619,620,621,622,623,624,625,626,627,628,629,630,631,632,633,634,635,636,637,638,639,640,641,642,643,644,645,646,647,648,649,650,651,652,653,654,655,656,657,658,659,660,661,662,663,664,665,666,667,668,669,670,671,672,673,674,675,676,677,678,679,680,681,682,683,684,685,686,687,688,689,690,691,692,693,694,695,696,697,698,699|
|700,701,702,703,704,705,706,707,708,709,710,711,712,713,714,715,716,717,718,719,720,721,722,723,724,725,726,727,728,729,730,731,732,733,734,735,736,737,738,739,740,741,742,743,744,745,746,747,748,749,750,751,752,753,754,755,756,757,758,759,760,761,762,763,764,765,766,767,768,769,770,771,772,773,774,775,776,777,778,779,780,781,782,783,784,785,786,787,788,789,790,791,792,793,794,795,796,797,798,799|
|800,801,802,803,804,805,806,807,808,809,810,811,812,813,814,815,816,817,818,819,820,821,822,823,824,825,826,827,828,829,830,831,832,833,834,835,836,837,838,839,840,841,842,843,844,845,846,847,848,849,850,851,852,853,854,855,856,857,858,859,860,861,862,863,864,865,866,867,868,869,870,871,872,873,874,875,876,877,878,879,880,881,882,883,884,885,886,887,888,889,890,891,892,893,894,895,896,897,898,899|
|900,901,902,903,904,905,906,907,908,909,910,911,912,913,914,915,916,917,918,919,920,921,922,923,924,925,926,927,928,929,930,931,932,933,934,935,936,937,938,939,940,941,942,943,944,945,946,947,948,949,950,951,952,953,954,955,956,957,958,959,960,961,962,963,964,965,966,967,968,969,970,971,972,973,974,975,976,977,978,979,980,981,982,983,984,985,986,987,988,989,990,991,992,993,994,995,996,997,998,999|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

number of chunks or partitions : 10
```

UPDATE :   randomsplit  example :

```
  import spark.implicits._

  val t1 = sc.parallelize(0 until 1000).toDF("id")
println("With Random Split ")
  val dfarray = t1.randomSplit(Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1));
  println("number of dataframes " + dfarray.length + "element order is not guaranteed ")
  dfarray.foreach {
    df => df.show
  }
```

Result : Will be split in to 10 dataframes and order is not guaranteed.

```
With Random Split 
number of dataframes 10element order is not guaranteed 
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  2|
| 10|
| 16|
| 30|
| 36|
| 46|
| 51|
| 91|
|100|
|121|
|136|
|138|
|149|
|152|
|159|
|169|
|198|
|199|
|220|
|248|
+---+
only showing top 20 rows

+---+
| id|
+---+
| 26|
| 40|
| 45|
| 54|
| 63|
| 72|
| 76|
|107|
|129|
|137|
|142|
|145|
|153|
|162|
|173|
|179|
|196|
|208|
|214|
|232|
+---+
only showing top 20 rows

+---+
| id|
+---+
|  7|
| 12|
| 31|
| 32|
| 38|
| 42|
| 53|
| 61|
| 68|
| 73|
| 80|
| 89|
| 96|
|115|
|117|
|118|
|131|
|132|
|139|
|146|
+---+
only showing top 20 rows

+---+
| id|
+---+
|  0|
| 24|
| 35|
| 57|
| 58|
| 65|
| 77|
| 78|
| 84|
| 86|
| 90|
| 97|
|156|
|158|
|168|
|174|
|182|
|197|
|218|
|242|
+---+
only showing top 20 rows

+---+
| id|
+---+
|  1|
|  3|
| 17|
| 18|
| 19|
| 33|
| 70|
| 71|
| 74|
| 83|
|102|
|104|
|108|
|109|
|122|
|128|
|143|
|150|
|154|
|157|
+---+
only showing top 20 rows

+---+
| id|
+---+
| 14|
| 15|
| 29|
| 44|
| 64|
| 75|
| 88|
|103|
|110|
|113|
|116|
|120|
|124|
|135|
|155|
|213|
|221|
|238|
|241|
|251|
+---+
only showing top 20 rows

+---+
| id|
+---+
|  5|
|  9|
| 21|
| 22|
| 23|
| 25|
| 27|
| 47|
| 52|
| 55|
| 60|
| 62|
| 69|
| 93|
|111|
|114|
|141|
|144|
|161|
|164|
+---+
only showing top 20 rows

+---+
| id|
+---+
| 13|
| 20|
| 39|
| 41|
| 49|
| 56|
| 67|
| 85|
| 87|
| 92|
|105|
|106|
|126|
|127|
|160|
|165|
|166|
|171|
|175|
|184|
+---+
only showing top 20 rows

+---+
| id|
+---+
|  4|
| 34|
| 50|
| 79|
| 81|
|101|
|119|
|123|
|133|
|147|
|163|
|170|
|180|
|181|
|193|
|202|
|207|
|222|
|226|
|233|
+---+
only showing top 20 rows

+---+
| id|
+---+
|  6|
|  8|
| 11|
| 28|
| 37|
| 43|
| 48|
| 59|
| 66|
| 82|
| 94|
| 95|
| 98|
| 99|
|112|
|125|
|130|
|134|
|140|
|183|
+---+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what if I wanted it dynamically. Like I don't know the count of total records but I still want it to have chunks of 100. 

I guess repartitionByRange only helps when you know exactly how many records you have and we divide it into 10 partitions because we wan want 100 each

Comment: updated randomsplit example as well. AFAIK there is no other way to achive this.

Comment: @RamGhandiyaram Thanks for sharing your thoughts on a possible solution. randomSplit might definitely no be an option and repartitionByRange can work if we change the partitions count dynamically. But I have edited my question with the solution that worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/q/61219832/12322995  Thank you

Comment: `df.collect.grouped(10)` is wrong it may cause OOM for large data since you are collecting .. you count approx logic can be applied for repartitionBy Range  to know number of partition you want you can do count approx and divide by 100 and pass that to repartitionByRange should work